# textarea does not work in angular6

Tags: angular, forms, textarea, angular6

I am using angular 6 and I try to put a textarea in a form.

This is my code so far

```
<textarea rows="20" cols="50" id="mailtext" required [(ngModel)]="mailtext" name="mailtext" #mailtextvalidityMsg="ngModel" >Hi there</textarea>
```

I can see the text area in the html, but the "Hi there" text is not rendered. I dont get any errors in my console.

If I remove the `[(ngModel)]="mailtext" name="mailtext" #mailtextvalidityMsg="ngModel"` it works.

This is happening only for the textarea. For other fields in the same form, such as `input type="email"`, there is no problem.

What am I missing?

Thanks

EDIT

I forgot to mention that I want to have line breaks and a link in the textarea, something like

```
Hi there , 

this is the code you have to use 

Click here
```

I want to have line breaks and the `Click here` must be a link

If I do

```
mailtext:any;
this.mailtext = 'Hi there,'+<br>+'this is the code you have to use';
```

I get `Hi there,NaN`

Thanks

Comment: It's probably being replaced the the `ngModel` binding at runtime. If you want to have a default value, just set `this.mailtext = 'Hi there'` in the component

Comment: @user184994 Great  catch. Turn this in to a regular answer, so I can set it as the accepted on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably being replaced the the `ngModel` binding at runtime.

If you want to have a default value, just set `this.mailtext = 'Hi there'` in the component

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want to have line breaks and links inside the textarea. How do I do this, while setting a value in the component ? Thanks again

Comment: @slevin Line breaks should work with a `\n` in the string, so `A\nB` would display `B` on a new line. Links on the other hand I don't think will be possible inside a textarea